# Jupyter Kernel restarts

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook

I'm running a Jupyter instance on AWS EC2.  I regularly get the message shown below, where the kernel disconnects and has to reset:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cjBF.jpg

This happens especially when I try to install new libraries with pip or run long sets of code, and I've had other difficulties such as having to shut down and restart the instance to register google.protobuf properly so I could import tensorflow.  What could be causing this behavior?  Would it be a Jupyter memory issue, the server that's hosting the Jupyter, or something else?